# Rails ActiveAdmin max column length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In a Rails app using ActiveAdmin, one of my fields is printing an enormous length of text in a very narrow column and causing a single db row to take up an entire screen vertically. I only want ActiveAdmin to show the first ~50 chars with an ellipsis if it exceeds.

```
index do
  column :too_long
...
```

I am looking for something like this

```
index do
  column :too_long, :max => 50
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use something like

```
 index do
   column "TOO LONG" do |object|
      object.too_long.slice(0, 50)
   end
  #.....
 end
```

I have not tested this but something like this should work.

check more details in docs http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the helper function [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) for this

```
index do
   id_column
   column :too_long do |my_resource|
      truncate(my_resource.too_long, length: 50)
   end
   actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Active admin to display a long text with a tooltip looks like below:

```
index do
    column "some_field" do |d|
        div(title: d.some_field) do
            truncate(d.some_field, length: 150)
        end
    end
end
```